# I want to get rid of "-"(dash) in csv file(in Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have csv files and in the table, when there's no number, it has dash signs.

All I know to solve it is to replace "-" with "" but it will affect "minus" signs.

What should I do to remove dash signs when it's not actually minus signs followed by numbers?

Thank you

Comment: Can you share an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly remove those signs when you convert the csv to a pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.read_csv("yourfile.csv",na_values=["-"])
```